# Double quotes in Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

How can I get a string inside double quotes using regular expression?

I have the following string:

```
<img src="http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg" alt="">
```

I want to get the string `http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg alt=""` outside.
How can I do this using regular expression?

Comment: Do you always want to have the alt tag as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why you want the alt tag as well, but this regexp does what you want:
Group 1 is the url and group 2 is the alt tag. I would possibly modify the regexp a bit if there can be several spaces between img and src, and if there can be spaces around '='

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img src=\"([^\"]*)\" (alt=\"[^\"]*\")>");
Matcher m = 
    p.matcher("<img src=\"http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg\" alt=\"\"> " + 
    "<img src=\"http://yahoo.com/img2.jpg\" alt=\"\">");

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + "  " + m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg  alt=""
http://yahoo.com/img2.jpg  alt=""
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img src=\"(.*?)\".*?>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<img src=\"http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg\" alt=\"\">");
if (m.find())
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

However, if you're parsing HTML consider using some library: regex are not a good idea to parse HTML. I had good experiences with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/): here's an example:

```
String fragment = "<img src=\"http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg\" alt=\"\">";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(fragment);
Element img = doc.select("img").first();
String src = img.attr("src");
System.out.println(src);
```

Comment: The pattern is too greedy when looking for `>`

Comment: @Kaj: thanks :) ... and I voted your answer too, because I see that you provide a slightly different regex matching also the `alt=""` part ... I don't know why the op wants it.

Comment: @MarcoS Thanks. I think that is a typo of the OP, but it's possible that he might want the value of the alt tag as well. Just have to wait and see if the OP answers my question regarding the alt tag.

Comment: @Kaj: I would say it's a typo rather than a type :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
String url = "";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=src=\")[^\"]*(?=\")");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<img src=\"http://yahoo.com/img1.jpg\" alt=\"\">");
if (m.find())
    url = m.group());
```

The parser will take every char *except* `"` *after* `src="` and *before* `"`

Comment: I don't know how to read the post by the op, but his example shows that he wants the alt tag as well. (Don't know why, and don't know why he wants the tag as well, and not only the value of the alt tag)

Comment: @Kaj - I see, but I skipped that part because that mixture of a *link url* and the `alt` attribute (name and value in xml notation) smelled like typo ;)